# How to show $x$ and $y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> How would one solve the following set of questions? I tried a few methods but I'm not sure if it's correct.
>
> Given $$p(x=a,y=1)=1$$ $$p(x=b,y=1)=0$$ $$p(x=a, y=2)=0$$ $$p(x=b, y=2)=0$$
>
> Show that
>
> $$p(x=a)=1$$$$p(x=b)=0$$ $$p(y=1)=1$$ $$p(y=2)=0$$
>
> Hence, show that $x$ and $y$ are independent $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$

Attempt

$p(x=a, y=1) = 1$ and $p(x=b, y=1)=0$
therefore $p(x=a)=1$ and $p(x=b)=0$

It this partially correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(X=a)=P(X=a, Y=1)+P(X=a, Y=2)=1+0=1$$

To check if it is independent, verify if $P(X=x,Y=y) =P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ for all possible $x$ and $y$. There are only $4$ cases to check.

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks very much!